# Why does Keras not return the full sequence of cell state in lstm layer?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, attention-model

I am trying to implement an attention mechanism where I need the full sequence of the cell state (just like the full sequence of the hidden state). Keras `LSTM` however only returns the last cell state:

```
output, state_h, state_c = layers.LSTM(units=45, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
```

`state_c` has shape `(batch size, 1, 45)` where output (which is the full sequence hidden state) has shape `(batch size, 5, 45)`. 5 is the time window length

Why does Keras not return the full sequence cell state? and is there a better approach to get the full sequence of cell state than the approach below?

```
full_hidden, full_cell, outputs = [], [], []
state = None
input = layers.Input(shape=(time_window,features), dtype='float32')
output = layers.LSTM(units=45, return_state=True)

for i in range(time_window):
    input_t = input[:, i, :]
    input_t = tf.expand_dims(input_t, 1)
    out, state_h, state_c = lstm(input_t, initial_state=state)
    state = state_h, state_c
    full_hidden.append(state_h)
    full_cell.append(state_c)
    outputs.append(out)
```

Comment: What type of attention are you implementing? For some, you only need the last cell state.

Comment: I am implementing [DA-RNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.02971.pdf). Equation 8 suggests I need every cell state for each time step.

Comment: Have anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the flag [`return_sequences`](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) to `True` to get all the temporal states. The flag `return_state=True` that you use makes the layer to return the final state.

Comment: return_state=True still will not return the cell state for each time step. It returns the cell state at the last time step

Comment: Yes, this is what I am saying, you need to set `return_sequences` to `True`.

Comment: again, that still return the cell state's last value